# lists styled with multiple columns breaks in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is my second go at this issue and i still cannot come up with a fix. my problem relates to taking a list of links and splitting it into columns. I run a site in which the users have multiple usernames and so a jumplist is dynamically generated. This means any type of static solution wont work. The list needs to be able to stretch dynamically with the content.

```
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
```

Tossing that in should have solved my problem. And did, or so I thought, I only had messed with it on firefox and it performed exactly how i pictured. Then i got complaints from chrome users. Seems that in chrome, the column refuses to let the list items be put side by side and only takes the width of the largest. I'm not sure quite how to explain it better than that, so i made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Traesoleine/LepMN/) to demonstrate. It shows the original list I made, alongside putting in the `column-count` property.

if you look at it in firefox or opera, it looks just fine and how its intended to look, the browser takes the size of all three columns. Looking at it in chrome you see all three columns but it is constrained by the length of the largest item in the column before being split into multiple columns, which can be seen by using inspector to switch the column rule on and off.

So now I ask, how can I get chrome to respect my columns and display this the right way? or is it even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it with a width on the ul container, I hope it'll help :

```
.multi ul {
    width:500px;
}
```

See your [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/LepMN/1/) fiddle. You're right on firefox and opera it's working and not on chrome, I tried some other css [columns parameters](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/) without success.

Comment: thanks, and i knew that particular solution worked, but it needs to be dynamic, as some people have one alternate username and some have 20+ so a fixed width would leave it overly large for the single user, while possibly not being large enough if someone had many usernames and some happened to be really long.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I didn't even know column-count property existed in CSS. Learned something new.

But since it is not supported in IE, let me propose an alternate solution.
It is using Twitter Bootstrap like row/span layout styles. CSS will become much simpler if you include bootstrap.

The downside is that it will list the items left-to-right, instead of top-to-bottom in each columns.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eX59a/3/)

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper left">
    <div class="single">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dolor sit amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">consectetur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">adipiscing elit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sit amet erat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">congue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">quis dolor in orci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">venenatis vel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vivamus</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper right">
    <div class="multi">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dolor sit amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">consectetur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">adipiscing elit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sit amet erat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">congue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">quis dolor in orci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">venenatis vel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vivamus</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.single, .multi {
    display:block;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.single ul {
    width:205px;
}
.multi ul {
    width:615px;    
}
ul {
    background-color:#545454;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
li {
    background-color:#CACACA;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    width:180px;
}
a {
    text-align:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.left {
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.right {
    left: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, its works for this list but, my issue is a dynamic one. if the user had a single username there would be one short link this would look very wrong, the converse would be true where if there were more links than presented in the demo, esp. with longer text, it has the oppourtunity to be too small and clip it off.

Comment: Ah, understood. In that case this fixed width solution is probably not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with a slight change in HTML and some other CSS changes

HTML:

```
<div class="multi">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dolor sit amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">consectetur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">adipiscing elit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sit amet erat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">congue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">quis dolor in orci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">venenatis vel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vivamus</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Which I believe is the right way to write a list.

CSS:

```
.multi li {
    display: inline-block;
       width:100%;
}
.multi a {
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px 10px;
    position:relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:#CACACA;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/LepMN/2/